# Transforming HTML table populated by database query into matrix-like summary table

Tags: html, sql, django, html-table

I have an HTML table that contains transaction-style information(date, category, and value) for each row. I would like to change this table from being a simple row-by-row table into a matrix-style summary table, taking in a `group by` query from my database and displaying the group by parameters as the column and row headers.

Query:

```sql
SELECT MONTH(date) as month, category, value
FROM transactions
GROUP BY month, category
```

Current Table (using a query without the group by):

```
Month  ||  Category  ||  Value
------------------------------
Jan    ||  Produce   ||  10
Jan    ||  Poultry   ||  20
Feb    ||  Poultry   ||  30
Feb    ||  Poultry   ||  20
```

Desired Table:

```
           ||  Jan  ||  Feb
------------------------------
Produce    ||  10   ||   0
Poultry    ||  20   ||  50
```

I have no trouble reading the data into my table or displaying it, but I have been struggling to figure out how to format or display a table or some alternative HTML object in the matrix-style I have described.

This is the HTML code to create my current table. I am using Django as my framework (hence the django syntax {{}} to populate my table). This does not seem like a Django problem to me, so I am not including any of that code, but I can if someone feels that's where the solution lies.

```html
<table id = 'transactions'>
    <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    {% for transaction in transactions %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ transaction.month }}</td>
        <td>{{ transaction.category }}</td>
        <td>{{ transaction.value }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Both front-end and back-end ideas or solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the SQL backend, use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    category,  
    MAX(CASE WHEN month = 'Jan' THEN value END) Jan,
    MAX(CASE WHEN month = 'Feb' THEN value END) Feb
FROM mytable
GROUP BY category
```

This should produce the correct row/column structure, and make it easier to display it in your frontend.

Comment: Guess I was focusing so hard on a front end solution that I missed the obvious and simple SQL solution. Thanks!